# Is it possible to trigger a Jenkins DSL job from a pipeline script without sandbox script approval

Tags: jenkins, permissions, jenkins-pipeline, sandbox

Below is my Jenkins pipeline code that helps trigger another build in the same folder and gets its log(console out).

```
     script {
        slaveJob = build job: "Stop_Start", parameters: [string(name: "va_environment", value: "${params.Environment}", trim: true),string(name: "action", value: "${params.Action}", trim: true)]
        println slaveJob.rawBuild.log
            }
```

As you can see from the below error, this requires approval of script by the Jenkins administrator.

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:265)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor$6.reject(SandboxInterceptor.java:289)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:409)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
```

Is it possible to do this with script approval by the admins?

Comment: The error comes from `slaveJob.rawBuild` (which is an equivalent of calling a method slaveJob.getRawBuild()`). You can either remove the 3rd line, or you have to ask your Jenkins administrator for approval to access this method. Removing the line seems to be a better choice imho.

Comment: How will i be able to trigger a different DSL job if i remove `rawBuild` @Szymon Stepniak

Comment: The 3rd line is not responsible for triggering the job, but it prints the log of the triggered job to the current console. It seems to be useless in the example you have shown.

Comment: Correct but i need the logs to be written here.